# Are the coins scattered around the castle only useful for health?

Tags: super-mario-64

There are four coins in the main hallway, and a number of them in the Boos in the yard. Is there anything to gain from them other than health? Do I get anything for collecting them, perhaps in a particular order?

Answer (score 11):

In answer to the title, yes.  In answer to the body, no :P

There's nothing special about those coins.  They won't trigger lives, secret passageways, or anything else.  As I noted on another answer before it was removed, there aren't 100 coins in/around the castle so you can't get a star from them either.